# define-type returning error on DrScheme

Tags: scheme

When I try to run define-type  on DrScheme, I get the error "reference to an identifier before its definition: define-type". Why is that happening?

I input:

```
(define-type GUI
    [label (text string?)]
    [button (text string?)
            (enabled? boolean?)])
```

and I get back:

> reference to an identifier before its
>   definition: define-type

Comment: When asking questions here, you should *always* try to post actual code that illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

define-type is not part of "basic" Scheme, it is part of "Typed Scheme". To use this language in Dr Scheme:

Make sure "Module" is selected in the dropdown at the bottom left of the window. Then in the top window, enter:

```
#lang typed-scheme
```

and press the "run" button.

Comment: Thanks.I did this.
My program at the top window is now:

#lang typed-scheme

 (define-type shape
   [square (side number?)]
   [rect (height number?) (width number?)]
   [circle (radius number?)])

but I still got error:

expand: unbound identifier in module in: define-type

could you help me?

Comment: @Robert Sorry, it looks as if I was wrong define-type-alias is from Typed Scheme, I'm not sure where you are getting define-type from. Can you post the URL for your source?

Comment: `define-type` is from the language that is specific to PLAI.  Ask your instructor where to get it and how to install it.

Comment: I had this problem too using plai, turned out to be some kind of character encoding problem from copy/pasting code from another source. I just had to remove `(define-type` and retype it.